# Component not updating on stateChange

Tags: reactjs

I would like the value of a TextField to be some computed value... as such, I have a controlled form, `ComputedValue`,  with a render method that looks like this:

```
render() {
    return <TextField
        value={this.state.value}
        key={this.props.id}
        id={this.props.id}
        label={this.props.label}
        inputProps={{
            readOnly: true
        }}
    />;
}
```

the `ComputedValue`'s state.value is set by pulling data from localStorage, doing some computation, and setting the state.  That method looks like this:

```
computeValue() {
    let computedValue="";

    // split the computation string into constituent components
    let splitCS = this.props.computationString.split(/([+,-,*,/,(,),^])/g);

    // replace all instaces of questionID's with their value
    for (let i = 0; i < splitCS.length; i++) {
        if (splitCS[i] !== '+' && splitCS[i] !== '-' && splitCS[i] !== '*' &&   splitCS[i] !== '/' &&
            splitCS[i] !== '(' && splitCS[i] !== ')' && splitCS[i] !=='^') {
                // splitCS[i] is a questionID
                let Q = getQuestionDataFromLSbyQuestionID(splitCS[i]); 
                splitCS[i] = Q.value;
            }
    }

    // check that all values returned 
    if(splitCS.includes("")) {
        console.log("null value was returned in ComputedValue question");
    } else {
        // rejoin string and send to eval (TODO: replace eval)
        let finalComputeString = splitCS.join('')
        computedValue = eval(finalComputeString);
    }

    // save value in state
    this.setState({
        value: computedValue
    }, () => {
        this.props.stateChangeHandler(this);
        this.render();
    }
    );

    return computedValue;
}
```

This component is leaf in a tree of questions; as their values change (my app syncs LS and the head parent's state) I'd like the computed value to change.

Here are my two issues:

1) Given I call `setState` inside the computeValue function... I'm unable to call it from within the render function.  However, if I only call it from the `componentWillMount` lifecycle function, it `computeValue` only gets called once (upon mounting) and then not again.  If I call it from the `componentWillUpdate`, I get an infinite loop.  I can put a stop in this loop by comparing nextStates and what not... but that doesn't seem like the best way.

2) renders are not triggered by an update of the parent's state.. including trying a 'forceUpdate') (though they do appear to be triggered by hovering over the mouse and various other UI things).

Comment: Function you have posted is different than you bind in text field

Comment: True.  It's a ready-only text field, so the onChange should never fire.  (right?)   I've removed it for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

> Given I call setState inside the computeValue function... I'm unable
>   to call it from within the render function.

I would like you to elaborate or clarify this statment.

> However, if I only call it from the componentWillMount lifecycle
>   function, it computeValue only gets called once (upon mounting) and
>   then not again.

Yes componentWillMount is a lifecycle hook that is called only once when the component is going to be added in the tree.

> If I call it from the componentWillUpdate, I get an infinite loop.

This lifecycle hook is called before your component gets updated. So if you set your state here it will again call this function and it will make a infinite loop.

> I can put a stop in this loop by comparing nextStates and what not...
>   but that doesn't seem like the best way.

You can always do the comparing and update the state. There is nothing like a wrong way in doing so.

> renders are not triggered by an update of the parent's state..
>   including trying a 'forceUpdate')

You should never call `render` explicitly. It is not a correct practice because it hinders normal flow the react.

I would like you to test the setstate

```
this.setState(() => ({
    value: computedValue
}), () => {
    console.log("working")
    this.props.stateChangeHandler(this);
}
);
```

The problem seems to be the `()` in `({ value: computedValue })`. Give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is in your second observation. [renders are not triggered by an update of the parent's state]. guess what triggers render from the Parent? props

so, instead of putting your value in the state, put it in the prop, that way if the parent changes it, your component changes.

Hope this helps

Comment: props are read-only... so I'm assuming you are saying the 'value' of this component should be stored in the parent component and simply passed to this one.
... which then begs the question, wouldn't EVERYTHING basically need to be stored in the root/parent component?
... other, peer components to this one, update their state as expected (via onChange).  This one needs to update based on changes in peer components.

Comment: If the design pattern is bound to change in peer components, maybe I should ask, how often do you call computeValue()?

Comment: Ideally, it would be when one of the values it's computing changes.  In reality, it's every time someone presses a key.

Comment: Then, just call setState() on your key press event handler. thar should work